# geom_point color is not correct

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm trying to plot points from a csv using ggmap. The input csv has latitude, longitude, and hex color value (as well as a seed used to create the color value). However, the hex for the point and the actual color of the point don't match. Why is that?

[The current output](https://imgur.com/a/cppa7hS)

My code:

```
library(ggmap)

stores <- data.frame((read.csv(file="./mapData")

# Fetch the map
madison = get_map(location = location, source = "osm")

# Draw the map
madisonMap = ggmap(madison)


# Add the points layer
madisonMap = madisonMap + 
  geom_point(data = stores, 
             aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, colour = Color), 
             size = 5)
```

Example subsection of the dataset:

```
 Latitude, Longitude, Seed, Color
 45.508785, -122.632101 , 8, #22DD00
 45.515093, -122.642574, 11, #55AA00
 45.485144, -122.596184, 15.3, #9F6000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you map color to a hex value, ggplot will by default interpret that as a character string. To make it parse that as a color, add `+ scale_color_identity()`.

```
ggplot(mtcars[1:30,] %>% 
         mutate(color = rep(c("#22DD00", "#55AA00", "#9F6000"), times = 10)), 
       aes(wt, mpg, color = color)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars[1:30,] %>% 
         mutate(color = rep(c("#22DD00", "#55AA00", "#9F6000"), times = 10)), 
       aes(wt, mpg, color = color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it with `scale_colour_manual`
I assume the color is supposed to represent Seed

```
madisonMap = madisonMap + geom_point(data = stores, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude,colour=as.factor(Seed)), size = 5) + 
                      scale_colour_manual(values=stores$Color,labels=as.factor(stores$Seed),name='Seed')
```

[image]

Comment: The color is a gradient based on the seed. Is it possible to then display as a gradient rather than discrete colors? The legend looks bad right now with the discrete labels.

Comment: Not sure why, but [this is the image](https://imgur.com/a/gJBlfQi) I'm getting with the above code. It's like the colors have completely changed. I gave it a green/red gradient, yet I'm seeing yellows, blacks, blues, and pinks for some reason.